# How to rerun controllers after global data is resolved?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I resolve data on application load in a run block...

```
.run(function($rootScope, $q, teams, schools, news, games){
  // go out and grab all the relevant data
  $rootScope.showSplash = true;
  $q.all([
    $rootScope.school  = schools.get({id:1}),
    $rootScope.teams   = teams.query({id:1}),
    $rootScope.news    = news.query({id:1}),
    $rootScope.games   = games.query({id:1})
  ]).then(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $rootScope.showSplash = false;
      $rootScope.$digest();
    }, 1000);
  })
})
```

I have a controller whose scope should clone the data via $rootScope...

```
.controller('NewsDetailCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.newss = $scope.news.filter(function(news){
        return news.id == $routeParams.id;
    }).shift();
});
```

If the user is on the new-detail.html page, no data is present because the $scope clones an empty array.  Is it possible to rerun the controllers when that information is received?

Comment: You are doing this the wrong way. Controller goal is just to expose datas to the view, so you have to create a provider service who provide filtered datas, and the controller must be watching on it. In your controller, use a $watch on yourService.filteredDatas, and then update the view. Controller must not content any business code / reflexion / action.

Comment: Hey @Nico thanks for the response. I didn't realize filtering in the controller constituted business logic.  The reason I have my app set up this way is so I can request the data only once on page load instead of requesting data on each page request because the data doesn't change often (every two days, maybe).  The user can request new data on swipe and hold (snap-chat style) but that's it.

When you say "In your controller, use a $watch on yourService.filteredDatas, and then update the view", what does "then update the view" mean?

Comment: If there is no async call, use a promise or a $watch is a non sense, you only have to load your data as you already did, and then, load the news you want from an already loaded stack. An example I just wrote here: http://jsfiddle.net/yy5J3/

Answer (score 2):

For a better solution you could create a decorated cache.

Take a look at the decorator provider in angularJS:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide

This will allow you to wrap your biz logic in the service.  Then decorate that service with a caching layer in order to make sure that it is only retrieved once.  I can post an example if needed.

** UPDATE TO ADD EXAMPLE **

```
var upstream = angular.module('thirdParty', []);
upstream.service('emailService', function() {
  this.email = "";

  this.setContent = function(content) {
    this.email = content;
  };

  this.send = function(recipient) {
    return 'sending "' + this.email + '" to ' + recipient;
  };
});

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['thirdParty']);

app.config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('emailService', function($delegate) {
    // myApp depends on the emailService from a third-party module, but the service is lacking a way to send email with signature.
    // To avoid reinventing the wheel and, as well as, maintaining a good habit of leaving third-party module intact, 
    // I use $provide.decorator here to enhance emailService.
    $delegate.sendWithSignature = function(recipient, signature) {
      return 'sending "' + this.email + '" to ' + recipient + " by " + signature;
    };
    return $delegate;
  });
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, emailService) {
  emailService.setContent("Greeting!!");
  $scope.emailComplete = emailService.sendWithSignature('a@a.com', 'tamakisquare');
});
```

I've added an example usage of a decorator. Hopefully that helps

Comment: Looking into this now.  I think I'll try to implement a local cache too so I can basically operate off of that information.

Comment: From what i've seen that's also one of the most common uses for a decorator pattern as well.  It's usually used for either monitoring of a service or adding a cache layer.  Although, that's only a couple of its uses.